# Treatment of categorical variables in rpart

Tags: r, decision-tree

I wonder how `rpart` treats categorical variables. There are several references suggesting that for unordered factors it looks through all combinations. Actually, even the [vignette](http://cran.irsn.fr/web/packages/rpart/vignettes/longintro.pdf) at the end section 6.2 states

> (F)or a categorical predictor with m levels, all 2^m−1 different possible
>   splits are tested.

However, given my experience with the code, I find it difficult to believe. The vignette shows a supporting evidence that running

```
rpart(Reliability ~ ., data=car90)
```

takes a really long, long time. However, in my case, it runs in seconds. Despite having an unordered factor variable with 30 levels.
To demonstrate the issue further, I have created several variables with 52 levels, meaning that 2^51 - 1 ~ 2.2 10^15 splits would need to be checked if all possibilities were explored. This code runs in about a minute, IMHO proving that all combinations are not checked.

```
NROW = 50000
NVAR = 20

rand_letters = data.frame(replicate(NVAR, as.factor(c(
  letters[sample.int(26, floor(NROW/2), replace = TRUE)],
  LETTERS[sample.int(26, ceiling(NROW/2), replace = TRUE)]))))
rand_letters$target = rbinom(n = NROW, size = 1, prob = 0.1)

system.time({
  tree_letter = rpart(target ~., data = rand_letters, cp = 0.0003)
})
tree_letter
```

What combinations of categorical variables are ACTUALLY checked in `rpart`?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question but I found [this link](https://freakonometrics.hypotheses.org/20736) that might answer some of it.

Bottom line is that rpart seems to be applying a simple algorithm:

- First, sort the conditional means, p_i = E(Y|X = x_i)
- Then compute Gini indices based on groups obtained from that ordering.
- Pick the two groups giving the maximum of these Gini indices.

So it should not be nearly as computationally expensive.

However, I personally have a case where I have a single categorical variable, whose categories are US states, and rpart overtimes when trying to use it to produce a classification tree. Creating dummy variables and running rpart with the 51 variables (1 for each state) works fine.